# Access Play framework's embedded H2 database when in production mode

Tags: database, playframework, h2

Is there a way to access Play framework's embedded H2 database (`db=fs` in application.conf) when the application is in `prod` mode? (like with the `/@db` url, which doesn't work in this mode) I use Play version 1.2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @db url is disabled in PROD mdoe for security reasons. In fact, any URL-based access to the database would be very dangerous.

If you have access to the server, you can try connect via a JDBC client, using:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1 
jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1/mem:db1
```

See [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases).